# codeigniter 3.1.9 xss_clean truncate text after % de

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

with xss_clean text getting truncated with % is used in the text field.

For example I have entered following text

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's

standard dummy text ever since the **15% deduction** to give refund.

But after applying xss_clean the text truncated to:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 15

I have checked xss_clean function in system/core/Security.php file and the issue at this code:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('#%(?:\s*[0-9a-f]){2,}#i', array($this, '_urldecodespaces'), $str);
```

it truncated text after the `% symbol`.

please help me solve the issue.

Comment: can you show the code where you actually use the xss_clean?

Comment: Hi,
I have just used on post data like:

$this->post_data = $this->post();
$this->post_data = $this->security->xss_clean($this->post_data,TRUE);